# Copy properties of bean containing list with Beanutils

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to copy a bean object through `Beanutils.copyproperties(Employee,EmployeeDTO)`. It doesn't throw me any exception while copying, but when i try to retrive `EmployeeDTO.getPhoneNumber()` it shows me a ClassCastException, because the DTO object shows the phone number list of employee object.

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

   private String name;

   private String salary;

   private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>(); 

   ....
}

public class EmployeeDTO implements Serializable {

   private String name;

   private String salary;

   private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>(); 
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List cannot be copied through Bean Utils. You need to first iterate the Phone Number List from DTO to form then make the final move

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with plain old reflection. This will go one level deep an accommodate Lists. Adapt to your needs.

```
Method[] srcMethods = installation.getClass().getMethods();
    for (Method srcMethod : srcMethods) {
        if (srcMethod.getName().startsWith("get")) {
            try {
                String setMethodName = srcMethod.getName().replaceFirst("get", "set");
                Class<?> returnType = srcMethod.getReturnType();
                if(returnType.equals(java.util.List.class))
                    returnType = java.util.Collection.class;
                Method thisMethod = this.getClass().getMethod(setMethodName, returnType);
                log.info("attempting get and set on " + srcMethod.getName() + " " + thisMethod.getName());
                thisMethod.invoke(this, srcMethod.invoke(installation));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("SDK model out of sync with CM model", e);
            }
        }
    }
```